# visual studio installer does not delete all file in uninstall

Tags: visual-studio, installation

I am using visual studio installer.
but when uninstalling - from add remove program it does not delete all files but leaves the folder with some files, how can I cause the uninstall delete all files?

Answer (score 0):

The installer only removes the files it installed. The files created the post installation are not removed. You must create a custom action to perform the cleanup.

Comment: what is the right way to handle this is I do not know which files exist? - different versions of the installer install different files. how to delete all files in installation folder?

Comment: You can use a custom action action

Answer (score 0):

To clean up after your software (delete some custom or user generated files), you should create a **Custom Action** and add it to the **Uninstall** section of your installer.

A custom action can be a Class Library that inherits from the `System.Configuration.Install.Installer` class.

Here's a sample implementation of the Uninstaller Custom Action:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class CustomUninstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public CustomUninstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        if (savedState != null)
        {
            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }

        string targetDir = @"C:\Your\Installation\Path";
        string tempDir = Path.Combine(targetDir, "temp");

        try
        {
            // delete temp files (you can as well delete all files: "*.*")
            foreach (FileInfo f in new DirectoryInfo(targetDir).GetFiles("*.tmp"))
            {
                f.Delete();
            }

            // delete entire temp folder
            if (Directory.Exists(tempDir))
            {
                Directory.Delete(tempDir, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: Handle exceptions here
        }
    }
}
```